# How to remove the Wordpress Virus wysija-newsletters completly?

Tags: wordpress, exploit, virus

Wordpress has been hacked by a vulerabilty of the Plugin: wysija-newsletters. Someone uploaded a Virus and it turned the WP Page into a hacking tool too.

How can I remove every change that wysija-newsletters did without a backup? (It is the page of a friend)

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the plugin writers they can help you find out the issue and also the way to solve the problem.On the [support page](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wysija-newsletters)